# Observable does not display the value in full

Tags: angular, observable

When I want display value from URL with Observable I have just one letters.

I try to log value, when I take back I have full value

My component :

```
export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {
article$: Observable<string>;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

}

ngOnInit() {
  this.article$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
          console.log(params.get('title'));
          return params.get('title');
      }
  )
  );

  console.log(this.article$);
}

}
```

Output console.log : `foobar`

My HTML :

```
<div *ngIf="article$ | async">
 {{article$ | async}}
</div>
```

Output : `r`

Comment: can you provide simply stackBlitz?

Comment: why you are using switchMap here?, try to use just map

Comment: Thank you with map it's work.. Idk why

Comment: what you did here it is `map`'s functional, `switchMap` is for switching to new inner observable

Answer (score 1):

Try using alias as and remove **`async`**

```
<div *ngIf="article$ | async as article">
 {{article}}
</div>
```

Comment: i just checked in sample project and it works fine. produce a demo with stackblitz